# fileManager.createFileAtPath always fails

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I try to call the `fileManager.createFileAtPath`-method, but it always fails.
My variable `success` is always `false`. I looked at some similar posts here but nothing fits my needs exactly.
Here is my code:

```
pListPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: String(reportsPath)).URLByAppendingPathComponent("myReports.plist", isDirectory: false)

                let data: NSData = NSData()
                var isDir: ObjCBool = false

            if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(String(pListPath), isDirectory: &isDir)
                {
                    print("File already exists")
                }
                else
                {

                    let success = fileManager.createFileAtPath(String(pListPath), contents: data, attributes: nil)

                    print("Was file created?: \(success)")
                    print("plistPath: \(pListPath)")
                }
```

**Here is how i tried to fix this:**

I tried to use the method

```
let success = NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(String(pListPath), contents: data, attributes: nil)
```

And also

```
let success = data.writeToFile(String(pListPath), atomically: true)
```

But nothing works. `success`is always `false`.
I also tried to give it a literal-String as a path, set `contents`to `nil` and I even changed the directory permissions where i want to put it to 777, but noting works. `success`is always false. I hope you can me help out of this.
Any help is highly appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Please show what path are you using? `reportsPath` and `pListPath`

Comment: Make sure the folder exists first, see https://github.com/onmyway133/EasyStash/blob/master/Sources/Storage.swift#L60

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(String(pListPath), isDirectory: &isDir)
```

You cannot use `String(...)` to convert a `NSURL` to a file path string,
you have to use the `path` method:

```
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(pListPath.path!, isDirectory: &isDir)
```

If `reportsPath` is also an `NSURL` then the same problem exists at

```
pListPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: String(reportsPath)).URLByAppendingPathComponent("myReports.plist", isDirectory: false)
```

which should be

```
let pListPath = reportsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myReports.plist", isDirectory: false)
```

Comment: This gets me every single time...

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you try to create file in folder that already exists.
First create folder, then you can create file at that path.

```
private class func assureDirPathExists(path: String)
{
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
    {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you are writing file relatively to user domain folder.

```
 // i.e. Caches, Documents...
 let rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
```

Probably, you are missing the slash character, or you skip some folder creation first.

If you have ...dir1/dir2/file.ext than you need to create dir1, then dir2 and finally file.ext.

Comment: thank you both. i only had to change creation line to: `let success = fileManager.createFileAtPath(pListPath.path!, contents: data, attributes: nil)` now it works. Thanks