# fileManager.createFileAtPath fails during unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsfilemanager

Currently I'm trying to create files during a unit test to see if I can retrieve the data after its created but the fileManager.createFileAtPath always fails.  I looked at this post: [fileManager.createFileAtPath always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069697/filemanager-createfileatpath-always-fails) I implemented the solutions to that answer but it still fails. This is what the unit test and accompanying function looks like:

```
internal func getCacheFolderPath() -> String {
    var folderPath = ""
    guard let path = self.urls(for:.cachesDirectory , in: .userDomainMask).last?.path else {
        return folderPath
    }

    folderPath = path + "/NetworkCache"
    if !self.fileExists(atPath: folderPath) {
        do {
            try  self.createDirectory(atPath: folderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    return folderPath
}

func test_createFile(){
    let path = sut?.getCacheFolderPath()
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path!) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    let isFileCreated = fileManager.createFile(atPath: path!, contents: mockData, attributes: nil)

    print(isFileCreated)//This always returns false
}
```

Comment: Which line is failing? What is the error?

Comment: @rmaddy it’s not that there is an error, it’s that the file is never created and returns false. I’m trying to get it to create the file and return true.

Comment: What is the actual value of `path`? And why not use `Data write(to:)` instead of `FileManager createFile`? Then you can see why it is failing.

Comment: @rmaddy The reason why its failing is that its saying that the file or folder doesnt exist. But it should since the directory is created first before creating the file,

Comment: @rmaddy  The data.write(to:) was a good call. There is a error NSError domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 512, I'm looking into it.

Comment: @rmaddy It looks like when the app is reset, its throwing a code: 4 error, the file doesn't exist.  I'm trying to create the file so I know it doesnt exist

Comment: @rmaddy Its working now, thanks!

Comment: If you think it will help others, post your solution as an answer below. Otherwise, you should delete this question.

Comment: @rmaddy good idea, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

Using the data.write(to:) instead of create file helped determine what the issue was.  It looks like I was creating a folder as a file path and trying to save a file to that path.  Since it was a file and not a folder it was returning that something already exists there.

Here is what the completed working code looks like:

```
  func saveData(data: Data, forFileName fileName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?)->()) {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.filePathForFileName(name: fileName))
        print("saveData:\(url)")
        do {
           // [data writeToFile:[self thdncFilePathForFileName:name] atomically:YES];
            try  data.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
              completionHandler(url)
        } catch  {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completionHandler(nil)

        }
    }


 func test_createFile(){

        var isSaved: Bool = false

        let path = sut?.getCacheFolderPath()

        let promise = expectation(description: "Completion Hander invoked")


        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path!)
        {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        sut?.saveData(data: mockData!, forFileName: filePath, completionHandler: { (url) in

            let fileManager = MockFileManager.default

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: self.sut!.filePathForFileName(name: self.filePath)) {
                isSaved = true
                print("FILE AVAILABLE")

            } else {
                isSaved = false
                print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
            }

            promise.fulfill()
        })

        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10, enforceOrder: true)
        XCTAssertTrue(isSaved)
    }
```