# How to get the root cause when createFile fails?

Tags: ios, file, error-handling, nsfilemanager

Trying to create a file using [createFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410695-createfile) API on `iOS`.

```
createFile(path, data, attr)
```

Document says,

#### Return Value:

`true` if the operation was successful or if the item already exists, otherwise `false`.

**I wonder if the operation was not successful, how can I get the exact cause of the failure?**. Expected some API like,

```
createFile(path, data, attr, &error)
```

Comment: Try execute the `createFile` using `do...catch`. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069762/940096)

Comment: @Praveenkumar thanks but exceptions wont cover the cause for `otherwise false` in documentation right?

Comment: Yeah, but we don't have such API which provides error clause.

Comment: Mean time, don't we get a exact cause through `do...catch`

Comment: @Praveenkumar we cannot even use do/catch because that api doesn’t throw.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Data.write(to:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779858-write) instead, it throws.

I use `FileManager.default.createDirectory` to create folders. I create `Data` that I want to write, and then I use `Data.write` to save it to disk.

```
var docDir = URL()
do {
    docDir = try FileManager.default.url(
        for: .documentDirectory,
        in: .userDomainMask,
        appropriateFor: nil,
        create: true
    )
} catch {
    fatalError("\(error)")
}
let subDir = docDir.appendPathComponents("mySubDir")
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
        at: subdir,
        withIntermediateDirectories: true,
        attributes: nil
    )
} catch {
    if (error as NSError).code == 516 {
        // "The file “x” couldn’t be saved in the folder “y” because a file with the same name already exists."
        // This is OK.
    } else {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
let filePath = subdir.appendingPathComponent("yourFileName")
let object:Codable = Whatever()
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(object)
do {
    try data.write(to: filePath)
} catch {
    fatalError("\(error)")
}
```

I do not know why Apple devs chose `FileManager.createFile` to be different. It seems strange to me.