# createFileAtPath method of NSFileManager returns false sometimes in 13.3.*

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

createFileAtPath method of NSFileManager returns false sometimes in 13.3.*(most 13.3.1), the disk space is sufficient and the errno is 17 which means the file has already exists but is not actually.

Comment: can you show some code? error at console log, ... More clearly more people can help you

Comment: BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:_cachedPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        if (!success) {
           LOG_PROTOCOL_ERROR(@"[music player] createFileAtPath fail, errno: %d, err: %s", (errno), strerror(errno));

Comment: Maybe [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069697/filemanager-createfileatpath-always-fails) can help you

Comment: thanks for reply,  but the path string and the directory in this case are both ok

Comment: can you send me sample code/project?